# GUI for mercurial on Snow Leopard

Tags: mercurial, osx-snow-leopard

Recently my IT guy decided to move over from SVN to mercurial, now I need a good GUI tool that will do the remote clone and so on. I tried murky and macMerial, I can't figure out how to get them either to work. I've been using "versions" for svn.

Thanks

Comment: Although not an answer, why did your IT guy decide to move things?  Was Snow Leopard a supported platform prior to the move?  If it was I'd be tempted to say "you broke it, you fix it" .. in a nice manner of course!

Comment: Too many SVN branch merging issues

Comment: @mat .. My concern isn't the state of SVN, its whether or not your IT person considered the impact of the change.  Putting you in the position where you have to research the effects of what he did is not what I would call reasonable

Comment: @Peter M: a programmer is able to figure out how to use Mercurial and matthewb shall find answers here and shall learn to use Mercurial in no time. Switching from CVS/SVN to a DVCS is not some random "decision to move things" but a very smart move from a productivity point of view. If you want you can even reproduce centralized workflow using DVCes. There's a reason while project like Linux, OpenJDK, etc. and companies like Google fell in love with DVCes. The "effects of what he did" are basically huge productivity gain (especially once the sh!t shall hit the fan): a more than reasonable move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) seems to have some [MacOS support](http://bytebucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/MacOSX).

Answer (score 1):

And so, what's wrong with Murky? You just have to download the latest zip, launch the application and either clone the repository (if you didn't do it already) or drag it into Murky's window. After that, just double click on the projet and voila!

Answer (score 1):

I found the [Sourcetree app](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) quite nice, which became available for free recently.

Comment: Beat me to it. A very elegant solution and supports Git and SVN also.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet the issue here is not that the GUI isn't good. It's that the underlying concepts of how SVN and Mercurial work are too different for things to translate well.

Learn Mercurial, and then use a GUI for convenience (although personally I don't bother using a GUI in anything except Perforce, and I'm not saying that because I think the perforce GUI is good)

Start [here](http://hginit.com/)